# Tomcat9: sometimes fast (~3k req/s), sometimes slow (~200req/s), same requests

Tags: performance, tomcat9

I wrote a web server in Java 8, packaged it as a war file, and deployed it to **Tomcat 9.0.48**.
Then I wrote a java app to send concurrent requests to the server to test its throughput.
When I run the client app on the **same host** as the server, the server can handle ~3000 requests per second.
But when the client app is run on a **remote host**, the server can only handle ~200 requests per second.
I am sending exactly the same set of 10,000 requests in these two cases. And the client is running on identical hardware in the two cases.

Please give me some hints on how to debug this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is my Connector config in **server.xml**:

```
<Connector port="80" 
               acceptorThreadCount="2"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="500"
               maxConnections="2000"
               acceptCount="2000"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Even if the TCP/IP connection is reused a request requires at least a roundtrip. If you have a 5 ms ping to the server and a **single threaded** client, 200 request per second is as much as you can get.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz the client is multi-threaded (100 threads), and ping roundtrip time to the server is about 11ms.  For every thread there can be up to 90 roundtrips in 1 second, totaling 9000 roundtrips in one second for 100 threads. So I believe this is not the bottleneck.